# Title in Web Browser Tabs not parsing HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have this issue, where I have a page named "Rates & Bookings".  The title is also given that name, and in the Web Browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE - Latest Versions) I get "Rates &amp; Booking" in the title.

How can this be solved?

[image]

Update: I just realised that it is inserting two & for escaping, however I do not know why this is done, as I have "Rates & Booking" in my Wordpress Title:

`<title>Rates &amp;amp; Booking | Falcon Court</title>`

Update #2: My question at this stage is, what is causing this? Can this be changed at database level, or is the rendering of titles which is the problem?

Update #3: This was solved by installing the SEO Ultimate plugin which handles the titles.

Comment: Please show your HTML source that produces this title.

Comment: Your missing `&` in your code. Is this the HTML code from the `view-source:`?

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;amp;` will of course be rendered as `&amp;`. Remove one `amp;`.
I guess you're double HTML escaping the title somewhere.

Comment: I realised that that is being escaped. I am trying to find it at database level to see why it was created with the double escape.